# Difference between preprocessor macros D__KERNEL__ and __KERNEL__

Tags: linux-kernel, macros, kernel-module

I am an absolute beginner in programming in linux kernel programming, so sorry if the question is to elementary.

Here https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch02s02.html I found following example:

```makefile
# Change it here or specify it on the "make" command line

KERNELDIR = /usr/src/linux

include $(KERNELDIR)/.config
CFLAGS = -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -I$(KERNELDIR)/include \ -O -Wall


ifdef CONFIG_SMP
CFLAGS += -D__SMP__ -DSMP
endif

all: skull.o

skull.o: skull_init.o skull_clean.o
$(LD) -r $^ -o $@

clean:
rm -f *.o *~ core
```

And my question is simply what is the difference between preprocessor macro `__KERNEL__` and the used `-D__KERNEL__`? Especially what is the meaning of "-D" here?  (by the way the same story with `MODULE` and `-DMODULE`).

Comment: This link will answer your questions - https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x208.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-D` is an [option to the compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1) (or preprocessor), telling it to define a macro.  So putting `-D__KERNEL__` on the compiler command line is exactly the same as putting `#define __KERNEL__` at the top of the file.  Likewise, `-DFOO` would define a macro named `FOO`.

No macro named `D__KERNEL__` is being defined anywhere here.